# Anyway to create a new Firefox profile on a server with no display? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: server, 18.04, firefox

I know this is easy to do if you have a display, but how to do it via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have firefox on a server, then I assume that you also have X11 installed.
Just forward your display and start firefox.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely